# How to tag an image for link

Tags: image, canvas, hyperlink, tags

Hi I want to tag an image for link.

Like facebook.

I know mapping at html code. But I need this at interface level.

Image will open and I will select some place on image and set a URL it. And I should multitag, not just one.

I dont know what should I search even. (Probably CANVAS)

Answer (score 0):

I found how its work

img has "**ismap**" attribute

You can control [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_ismap)